# How can I know when a Backbone View template is finished rendering?

Tags: backbone-views

I'm using Backbone.js, Require.js, and Underscore.js for a single page site.

I have a container view that handles the swapping in and out of sub-views.

For one of my sub-view, I need to know when the rendering of the HTML template is finished. Here's why: My html template for the sub-view (view_subview.html) contains an iframe and a form:

```
<iframe name="myIFrame" id="myIFrame"></iframe>

<form action="http://myendpt.com/do" method="get" id="myForm" target="myIFrame">
    <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="value1"/>
</form>
```

By submitting the form, the myendpt.com/do will handle generating the content to be displayed in the iframe.

I'm trying to figure out the timing of things so that I can submit the form once it has been loaded.

My sub-view looks like this:

```
define([
    'jQuery',
    'Underscore',
    'Backbone',
    'config',
    'text!templates/view_subview.html'
], function ($, _, Backbone, Config, tpl) {
    var SubView = Backbone.View.extend({

        template: _.template(tpl),

        initialize: function () {
        },

        render: function (eventName) {
            $(this.el).html(this.template({config: Config}));
            $('#myForm').submit();
            return this;
        },
    });
    return SubView;
});
```

The $('#myForm').submit() call in render() doesn't actually submit the form. Presumably this is because the HTML is still loading and the document is not yet ready.

If I move the $('#myForm').submit() call out to my container view, I can make it work, but I'd like SubView to own the submit of the form. My container view (and other, unrelated sub-views) should not need to know or care about what happens in SubView.

What's the best way to detect in SubView (and only in SubView) that the HTML is fully loaded so that I can call the submit?

Comment: I found something that works, but I'm not sure if this is the best answer. I discover Underscore.js's defer() function:

    render: function (eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template({config: Config, strings: Strings}));
        _.defer(function(){$('#imsForm').submit();});
        return this;
    },
        
According to the docs, defer() "defers invoking the function until the current call stack has cleared".

This seems to be delaying me enough so that I can invoke the submit, but will it always do the trick? Is there a more appropriate solution to my question?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you fire an event when your iframe is loaded and ready? your render function can bind to that event; something alone the lines of:

```
render: function(eventName){
    $(this.el).html(this.template({config:Config})
        .bind('formReady',function(){
             $('#myForm',this.el).submit();
        })
    return this;
}
```

and, just make your iframe fire the event onload:

```
<iframe onload='$(this).trigger('formReady');' .... >
```